# Calculate percentages of count in SQL relative to the category

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions, percentage

I am working in MySQL.
Initially I had a table that looks like this:

[image: initial database]

My task is to calculate the percentage of bookings that were cancelled for people that were in a long waiting list and for people that had short waiting.
After some manipulations I came up with the following code:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN days_in_waiting_list > (SELECT AVG(days_in_waiting_list) FROM Bookings) THEN 'Long wait'
ELSE 'Short wait' 
END AS waiting, 
is_canceled, COUNT(*), count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() AS perc_cancelled
FROM Bookings
GROUP BY waiting, is_canceled;
```

The resulting table:

[image: result]

But I want the percentages to be calculated for the category, not the whole table. So that the sum of percentages in Short wait was equal to 100, the same is for Long wait. I want it to be like this:

| waiting | is_cancelled | perc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Short wait | 0 | 0.61 |
| Short wait | 1 | 0.39 |
| Long wait | 0 | 0.32 |
| Long wait | 1 | 0.68 |

Is there a way to do this? I know that it is possible using over(partition by waiting), but it gives me the error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'waiting' in 'window partition by'

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, I didn't know how to do this, but I will research this topic, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use window functions to compute the average, then aggregation:

```
select waiting, is_cancelled, 
    count(*) / sum(count(*)) over(partition by waiting) as ratio
from (
    select b.*, 
        case when days_in_waiting_list > avg(days_in_waiting_list) over()
            then 'Long Wait'
            else 'Short wait'
        end as waiting
    from bookings b
) b
group by waiting, is_cancelled
order by waiting, is_cancelled
```

Comment: I don't know why other solutions don't work for me, maybe I have an old version on MySQL, but this works!! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

you want the percentages to be calculated per category, thus grouping by waiting category is needed for perc_cancelled

> count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over(partition by waiting) AS
> perc_cancelled

Comment: yep, I had the same idea. But it gives me an error "Unknown column 'waiting' in 'window partition by"

Comment: I just tried in MariaDB 10.5.8 and its working fine ...

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
CASE WHEN days_in_waiting_list > (SELECT AVG(days_in_waiting_list) FROM Bookings) 
THEN 'Long wait'
ELSE 'Short wait' 
END AS waiting, 
is_canceled,
COUNT(*) as subTotal, 
sum(count(*) over (partition by waiting ORDER BY is_canceled ASC) as totalSum,
FROM Bookings
GROUP BY waiting, is_canceled;
)
SELECT waiting,
is_canceled,
subTotal* (100.0)/totalSum as percentage
FROM cte
group by waiting,is_canceled
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! But it shows me that there is a syntax error, and I can't seem to figure out where.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as totalSum,
 subTotal* (100.0)/totalSum as percentage
 FROM Bookings
 GROUP BY wai' at line 7

Comment: can you try now?

Answer (score 1):

Creating the table with only the relevant data, and 40 random rows :

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  is_canceled INT DEFAULT FLOOR(RAND() * 2),
  days_in_waiting_list INT DEFAULT FLOOR(RAND() * 100)
);
INSERT INTO test () VALUES (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ();
INSERT INTO test () VALUES (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ();
INSERT INTO test () VALUES (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ();
INSERT INTO test () VALUES (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ();
```

Your were really close, just add `PARTITION BY waiting`:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN days_in_waiting_list > (
    SELECT AVG(days_in_waiting_list)
    FROM test
  ) THEN 'Long' ELSE 'Short' END AS waiting,
  is_canceled,
  COUNT(*),
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY waiting)
FROM test
GROUP BY waiting, is_canceled;
```

| waiting | is_canceled | count(*) | count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by waiting) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Long | 0 | 10 | 58.82353 |
| Long | 1 | 7 | 41.17647 |
| Short | 0 | 15 | 65.21739 |
| Short | 1 | 8 | 34.78261 |